# exclude dependencies that are not in depedency tree

Tags: maven, jar, maven-3, maven-dependency

When I run CLM scan on a jar, I am getting errors on a couple of libraries that I cannot find in the dependency tree for this maven project. Does anyone know how to exclude these dependencies or how I can find the root dependency for such transitive dependencies?

These are the libraries, both of which are not showing up in dependency tree

- fr.d2-si.ooso.0.0.1
- net.jcip.jcip-annotations.1.0

Comment: If a dependency is not in the dependency tree you can't exclude it...this sounds contradictable...Have you checked the parents ? How have you checked it?

Comment: @khmarbaise I pulled up maven dependency tree and searched for the library. If I run CLM scan through the maven clm plugin it doesn't detect this library either. This happens only with the jar. Im using maven shade plugin to prepare the jar.

Comment: @khmarbaise I guess a better question is, is it possible to have dependencies/libraries/jars in a shaded jar that are not defined in the maven dependency tree?

Comment: To answer your laster question: No. You have obviously overlooked something....